# RabbitMQ policy ttl override

Tags: rabbitmq, ttl

As Per RabbitMQ docs, it is defined what happens if there is a conflict between TTL on queue level and on message level.

It is not clear however what will take precedence in case of value conflict between a queue policy, queue declaration and per message TTL?